# interactive use of python console inside function scope without debugging mode

Tags: python, ipython, pdb

Here is what I want:

```
def f():
    x = 3
    return
```

Running that in a console and asking for x will not give anything since x is inside the function scope. The alternative is to copy all code in there in a new script, untab it and run it. Then I can ask for the value of x. If I have a complex function f() or even worse, methods inside classes, then it can be a frustrating operation, to copy/untabify/interactively outputing and code modification/copy back/tabify properly.

The only way I can get interactive console inside a function scope is by using pdb, but I want a clean console in there and not a debuger.

```
> x
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-25-401b30e3b8b5>", line 1, in <module>
    x

NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use IPython as a little bit better Python console:

```
import IPython

def some_complex_fn():
    x = 42
    IPython.embed()

some_complex_fn()
```

The interactive console then knows about `x`.

I can't find whether the "classic" Python console has any similar API.

If you are writing a web application then a debugger with web interface might be better - for example the [Werkzeug debugger](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/debug/#using-the-debugger) includes an interactive console too.

Comment: Thanks, this works but if I am already in IPython it seems to crash when opening a new Ipython console. From Python console it works though.

Comment: @grokkaine: You don't need to "open a new IPython console". And if it actually crashes (rather than raising an exception that probably explains the problem), you may need to file a bug against IPython.

Comment: @grokkaine: But anyway, the point of `embed` is that you run the program normally, from your bash/cmd/whatever shell, and it starts the IPython console up at the `embed` point, running in the environment of `some_complex_fn`, instead of starting it in a default global environment. It's basically what you asked for—like `pdb` but with a "clean console in there and not a debugger".

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that I edit my code with an editor, Spyder in my case, that has integrated IPython console (and Python). So if there is a way this could work from an IPython console it would be better. I am going to be more specific in my question, or maybe I can solve it myself.